# Replace hashtag in html body with a link without matching inline CSS in C#

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core

So i am trying to replace hashtags in a HTML string.

the problem i'm having is a that it matches `inline css` and `anchor tags` that point to a fragment in the page.

Take for example this html:

```
<div style="color:#ffff">#my_tag</div>
```

and the code:

```
public static string ReplaceHashtag(string input)
{
    Func<string, string> replacer = v => $"<a href=\"/tags/{v}\">{v}</a>";

    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\b?\#\w*\b", match => replacer(match.Value));
}
```

Will replace both css attribute and the hashtag with the anchor tag.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some sample data?

Comment: Good point, Done.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this with a wide range of input (just the sample input provided in the OP), but this pattern seemed to work for me:

```
        var pattern = @">.*(#\w*).*<";
        var tempHtml = "<div style=color:#ffff>#my_tag</div>";
        var ms = Regex.Match(tempHtml, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var tag = ms.Groups.Count > 0 ? ms.Groups[1].Value : string.Empty;
```

If you do not need the "#" in the captured group then just set the "#" outside the parenthesis like this:

```
var pattern = @">.*#(\w*).*<";
```

Please let me know if you have any questions or issues.